# Bash: How to assign echo'ed sentense to a variable in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, echo, variable-assignment

I tried searching existing questions but could not find one suites to my need.

I am trying to add a line to logs and the same has to be assigned to a variable QSubject so that, I can send an email with this as subject.

Is there a way to achieve the same in one line?

I tried this but learned that, it will only work if QSubject is a file.

```
echo "`date` No client_data records have been updated on `hostname` No Records to commit." > QSubject
```

Comment: What is wrong with two lines?

Comment: one line or one command? `QSubject="..."; echo "$QSubject" >>logs`

Answer (score 1):

```
toto=$(echo "`date` No client_data records have been updated on `hostname` No Records to commit.")
echo $toto
```

Output:

```
mar. 10 janv. 2023 16:27:03 No client_data records have been updated on CH15019 No Records to commit.
```

---

Or as @jhnc pointed out, even shorter:

```
toto="`date` No client_data records have been updated on `hostname` No Records to commit."
```

Comment: so, the execution of this statement happens whenever I call toto?

Comment: No, the value is assigned to toto when you assign it, not when you use toto. Moreover, you cannot "call" toto in the sense of calling a function. Toto is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all the output goes to stdout, you could pipe to `tee` and also print to stderr, which would not be captured by the command substitution:

```bash
$ var=$(echo "something" | tee /dev/stderr)
something
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="something"
```